# Disk cloning trouble due to slight size mismatch between source and target

Tags: clone, dd

I tried to clone sdb onto sdc but that failed due to a marginal size mismatch. I tried recovery options using gdisk to no avail. What are my options now for starting again from scratch? The source disk has lots of free space I don't need to clone.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress
1000165343232 bytes (1.0 TB, 931 GiB) copied, 100383 s, 10.0 MB/s[A
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device
238460+0 records in
238459+0 records out

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: EXTERNAL_USB    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F051C4EE-2188-44D2-8988-A6BFB515F49B

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048  644534271 644532224 307.3G unknown
/dev/sdb2  896489472  994146303  97656832  46.6G unknown
/dev/sdb3  644534272  675784703  31250432  14.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  675784704  896489471 220704768 105.2G unknown
/dev/sdb5  994146304 1105475583 111329280  53.1G unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9.1

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
```

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like Clonezilla that can handle this size mismatch automatically for you? Macrium Reflect is another tool that handles this elegantly, including Linux filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the partition layouts of both /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc using `fdisk -l` or `gdisk -l`. If they both match, ignore the messages and and have gdisk write out the correct backup partition table (using the `w` command – or maybe `v` first, then `w`).

You *might* also want to use `x` (Expert menu) → `e` (Relocate backup to the end of the disk), or gdisk might do that automatically, I'm not sure.

The backup partition table starts from the *end* of the disk, which means it will never be cloned correctly whether the target disk is smaller or larger than the source. (For example, even if the disk was larger and you had plenty of space to spare, the partition table would end up too far from the end and wouldn't be found.)

In the future, clone such disks in two steps:

1. clone just the partition layout using `sfdisk --dump` (which will properly generate a partition table in the destination disk);
2. clone each partition separately, using regular `cp`/`dd` (or its filesystem-aware variants; e.g. `ntfsclone` supports skipping unused space in NTFS partitions while `partclone` can do the same for Ext4).